# ORA-31114: XDB configuration has been deleted or is corrupted

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, export, corruption

ORA-31114: XDB configuration has been deleted or is corrupted

How to recreate the XDB configuration? Do I need to remove the existing component first?

By the way I can't run UTLRP scritp for the same reason.
I also cannot perform a datapump export.

Comment: `Master Note for Oracle XML Database (XDB) Install / Deinstall (Doc ID 1292089.1)` - https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1292089.1

Comment: Could not access the link, but anyways I got a solution and implemented it. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Removing XDB**

---

Run the following script to remove XDB

```
SQL> @C:\Oracle\Ora11\R2\rdbms\admin\catnoqm.sql
```

---

- It is very important to restart your database after removing XDB and before installing it again.

---

**Installing XDB**

---

The catqm.sql script requires the following parameters be passed to it when run:

A. XDB user password

B. XDB user default tablespace

*(Any tablespace other than SYSTEM, UNDO and TEMP can be specified.
The specified tablespace must already exist prior to running the script.)*

C. XDB user temporary tablespace

D. SecureFiles = YES or NO

*(If YES is specified, the XDB repository will use SecureFile storage.
If NO is specified, LOBS will be used.
To use SecureFiles, compatibility must be set to 11.2.
The tablespace specified for the XDB repository must be using
Automatic Segment Space Management (ASSM) for SecureFiles to be used.)*

Therefore the syntax to run catqm.sql is the following:

SQL> catqm.sql A B C D

```
SQL> @C:\Oracle\Ora11\R2\rdbms\admin\catqm.sql XDB XDB TEMP YES
```

---

Recompile all invalid objects within the database

```
SQL> @C:\Oracle\Ora11\R2\rdbms\admin\utlrp.sql
```

---

**Verify XDB Status**

---

Check registry

```
SQL> select comp_name, version, status from dba_registry where comp_id = 'XDB';


COMP_NAME            VERSION     STATUS
-------------------  ----------  -----
Oracle XML Database  11.2.0.1.0  VALID
```

---

Check invalid objects owned by XDB

```
SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type, status from dba_objects where owner = 'XDB' and status = 'INVALID';

no rows selected
```